# Kotlin Ternary conditional operator to typical if-else

Tags: kotlin, if-statement, ternary

Can someone turn this to if-else statements in Kotlin so that I can get an understanding of the code?

```
return email != null
        ? email.isEmpty
        ? "Please enter your email!"
        : RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]")
        .hasMatch(email)
        ? ""
        : "Please enter a valid email!"
        : "Please enter your email!";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ArtyomSkrobov's answer is a literal interpretation of that code.

I just wanted to add, since that original logic is very confusing: It can be rearranged in a when statement and use Kotlin standard library functions/classes to be a lot easier to understand:

```
return when {
    email.isNullOrEmpty() -> "Please enter your email!"
    !email.matches(Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]")) -> "Please enter a valid email!"
    else -> ""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return if (email != null) {
         if (email.isEmpty) "Please enter your email!"
         else if (RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]").hasMatch(email)) ""
         else "Please enter a valid email!"
       } else "Please enter your email!"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return if (email != null){
            when {
                email.isEmpty() -> "Please enter your email!"
                RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]"). hasMatch(email) -> ""
                else -> "Please enter a valid email!"
            }
        } else "Please enter a valid email!"
```